# Keep smallest n elements in set, discard others

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, set

I have a C++ STL set.

```
set<unsigned> baseSet;
```

I insert a bunch of numbers into it.

```
for(auto incoming : it->second.in) {
    baseSet.insert(incoming);
}
```

Now I want only the smallest n elements in the set. (I can switch the set's comparator to std::greater if that helps.) Sets don't seem to have a resize function like vectors. How can I shorten it? In-place would be great, and I definately want to take advantage of the fact that sets are sorted instead of doing all the sorting again.

Comment: The node based containers such as `std::set` are for specialized uses and you typically do not need and should not use them. You'd probably do better to use [a `vector` and `nth_element`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bddfcca5e9f8f267).

Comment: Unlike vectors, sets are made specifically for the case where you don't want repeated elements, which is exactly what I need for my application.

Comment: Even so, a vector is probably better. Just use `std::unique`. See [_Why you shouldn't use set (and what you should use instead)_](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf) and [_Why you should avoid Linked Lists_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo). (The second link refers to linked lists, but the information can also be applied to std::set.)

Comment: The point @bames53 is making is that constructing the set has complexity `O(N lg K)`, where `N` is the total number of insertions and `K` the number of distinct elements. Throwing everything in a vector which you then `sort`, `unique` and `resize` to `n` has complexity `O(N lg N)` but much more favorable constant factors. If `K` is not significantly smaller than `N`, or `N` is not "large", using a vector will almost certainly be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
if(baseSet.size() > n) {  // Use appropriate case if necessary
  auto it = base.begin();  // std::set<unsigned>::iterator
  std::advance (it, n);
  baseSet.erase(it, baseSet.end());
}
```

Find n<sup>th</sup> smallest element and erase range from that element to end.

**Option 2**

[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) onwards, you can also do this as following (Thanks to [bames53](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365496/bames53) for the comment)

```
baseSet.erase(next(begin(baseSet), n), end(baseSet));
```

**Option 3**

Another option (less recommended) is to keep deleting the elements once set reaches the size `n`.

```
for(auto incoming : it->second.in) {
    baseSet.insert(incoming);  // Insert conditionally if you bother about efficiency
    if(baseSet.size() > n) baseSet.erase(baseSet.rbegin());  // rbegin not to be confused with begin
}
```

Comment: To increment an iterator a certain number of times you can just use `next(it, n)` (C++11). `baseSet.erase(next(begin(baseSet), n), end(baseSet));`